# constructor with variadic multidimensional initializer_list

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, initializer-list

I have the following constructor:

```
class A {
    template<class ...T>
    A(std::initializer_list<T> && ... args);
}
```

And I have the code for that class:

```
A a1 = {{5.0f, 6.0f}, {-7.0f, 8.0f}};

A a2 = {{{5.0f, 3.f}, {6.0f, 7.f}}, {{-7.0f, 9.f}, {12.f, 8.0f}}};
```

`a1` can be compiled and `a2` can't be compiled. I understand, curly braces are only syntax sugar and not making the type by default, only when passing it to function with arguments that can be initilized with initilizer_list (e.g. `std::initializer_list<float>` in case of `A` and variable `a1`).

I wonder, is there any workaround that can help passing any dimensional `std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<...>...>...>` to function/constructor?

Comment: why you want this?

Comment: can't you specify the dimensions as (template or regular) parameters?

Comment: I want to parse tensor of any dimension to single dimension array and get it shape meanwhile. I've done parsing for any array-like container of any dimension and wanted to make similar parser for initializer_list of any dimension and found that it looks impossible. So, I've decided to make two template specializations: `template<class ...T> A(std::initializer_list<T> && ... args);` and `template<class ...T> A(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> && ... args);` that help me parse 3-dim lists. It is enough but I wonder if it is possible to make general solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked documentation and tried several different hacks but it will not work. 
So, basic answer would be it is not possible. 
It is not possible to make constructor or any other function accepting brace list of undefined number of brace lists because brace list has no type and cannot be implicitly converted to `std::initilizer_list<...>`.

Answer (score -2):

std::initializer_list...>...> , the form 
must have partial specialization , and then please reference to :
The program is ill-formed if an explicit or partial specialization of std::initializer_list is declared.

(since C++17)

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough but I was not talking about `std::initilizer_list<>` specialisation.